# XAML User Control not showing

Tags: c#, xaml

I have here a User Control where I'd like to overlay over my current area. Except it isn't showing up.

Here is my code for SpatialMode.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FilteringModule.View.SpatialFilterMode"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

        MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown"
        MouseUp="UserControl_MouseUp"
        MouseMove="UserControl_MouseMove">

<Canvas x:Name="SpatialCanvas" Background="Wheat">
    <Border 
            x:Name="dragSelectionBorder"
            BorderBrush="Blue"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Background="LightBlue"
            CornerRadius="1"
            Opacity="0.5"
            />
</Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

And where I call it:

```
    public void ShowSpatialFilterMode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SHOWING SPATIAL FILTER MODE?");
        _spatialFilterMode = new SpatialFilterMode();
        _spatialFilterMode.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

It writes to the console so I know it's hitting it correctly, except it's not showing?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you actually inserting it into the visual tree?

```
Grid.Children.Add(_spatialFilterMode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to add the control to some parent container?

Comment: Yes I do! The UserControl is my area for creating a draggable box over the current form. How do I add this to the parent container?